# Will Semaphore.tryAcquire(...) block or spin until permit is available?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

If an unfair Semaphore permit isn't instantly available, will the `tryAcquire(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` block until permit is available (i.e. yield execution), or will it spin until permit is available?

If the call spins and a system has a bunch of Semaphores, isn't the system running the risk of having a lot of spinning Semaphores?

Comment: Java doc [tryAquire](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire%28int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) is Self Explanatory

Comment: Damn, I must have read the wrong tryAquire JavaDoc... But as it's explained, it will not spin but yield execution.

Answer (score 4):

Per the javadoc:

> If no permit is available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of three things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the release() method for this semaphore and the current thread is next to be assigned a permit; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread; or
> - The specified waiting time elapses

This suggests that the thread is marked as blocked (put on blocked queue as Gray states) which allows the processor to do other work.

Comment: The "thread" is not released.  It just goes into the blocked queue.  Can you restate the last line?

Comment: It will not spin (`while(!canExecute);`). That's enough to know it will stay in some structure not using CPU.